# Facebook iPhone SDK - automatically PublishSteam (bypass Post to wall dialog)

Tags: objective-c, facebook

Trying to implement facebook wall post on the iphone app I'm working on.

How can I bypass the "Post to Your Wall" dialog box and just submit straight?
Basically I'm just trying to post a url and I don't really want to allow people to see that "Write something" textbox.

Here is the code that I have so far (from the sample app).

```
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];

NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"a long run", @"name",
                           @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                           @"it is fun", @"description",
                           @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil];
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                             actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                             attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                             nil];


[_facebook dialog:@"feed"
      andParams:params
    andDelegate:self];
```

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use one of the `- (FBRequest*)requestWith...` instance methods of the Facebook class.

Simple wall post using the old REST API:

```
NSString *facebookStatusMessage = @"facebookStatusMessage";
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                facebookStatusMessage, @"status",
                                nil];

FBRequest *request = [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"status.set" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

It's better to use the Facebook Graph API with `- (FBRequest*)requestWithGraphPath:` as the REST API will get deprecated.

Then also implement some of the FBRequestDelegate protocol:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    // result may be a dictionary, an array, a string, or a number, 
    // depending on the format of the API response
}
```